# Manned Spacecraft/Space Station design Requirements

Tags: crewed-spaceflight, design, space-station, engineering

I am looking for some document that summarizes all the aspects that need to be taken care of during design (structural resistance, life support system, thermal regulation, etc.). Something similar to this document would be best, just for all systems. https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/20210024855/downloads/BVAD_2.15.22-final.pdf I would mainly be interested in it for space stations and bases. I know that it is probably not a documentary that would be exactly according to my ideas. I would just need some summary to nudge me in the right direction.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Perhaps this might be of interest.

[JSC Design and Procedural Standards](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/20120015984/downloads/20120015984.pdf)

> This document provides design and procedural requirements appropriate
> for inclusion in specifications for any human spaceflight program,
> project, spacecraft, system, or end item. The term "spacecraft" as
> used in the standards includes launch vehicles, orbital vehicles,
> non-terrestrial surface vehicles, and modules.

This document has a long history at JSC and if you search [NASA NTRS](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/) for the title, you can find a number of older versions. Some of them incorporate pages going back to the 1960s.

Many lower-level standards and requirements documents are referenced in the document, many of which are also available in NASA NTRS.

Comment: I have one more question. For example, how does this differ from what you were referring to? https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/20150002993/downloads/20150002993.pdf
It has a lot less pages, but I don't see a major difference.

Comment: @SaturnV It looks like a newer, post-shuttle version (2015); I'm not familiar with that one.